# Is there a simple way to append header to symfony2's assetic generated assets?

Tags: symfony, assetic

I was using [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) with [gulp-header](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-header) and a bunch of tools to compile my scss and coffescript into css and js files. My gulpfile looks something like this:

```coffeescript
gulp = require('gulp')
pkg = require('./package.json')
plugins = require('gulp-load-plugins')()

#...

banner = [
  '/**'
  ' * ' + pkg.name + ' - ' + pkg.description
  ' * @version v' + pkg.version
  ' * @link ' + pkg.homepage
  ' * @license ' + pkg.license + ' ' + new Date().getFullYear()
  ' * @generated ' + new Date()
  ' */'
  ''
].join('\n')

gulp.task 'sass', ->
  gulp.src(css_dir + '**/*.scss')
  .pipe(plugins.sourcemaps.init())
  .pipe(plugins.sass
      style: 'compressed'
    )
  .on 'error', plugins.util.log
  .pipe(plugins.header(banner))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(css_dir))
  .pipe(plugins.sourcemaps.write())
  .pipe plugins.notify('Scss compiling done!')
  return

#... (same goes for coffeescript)
```

I'd like to accomplish the same using [Symfony2's asset management (assetic)](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html).

```yaml
assetic:
    debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
    use_controller: false
    bundles:        [ AcmeDemoBundle ]
    #java: /usr/bin/java
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        sass:    ~
        coffee:
            bin: /usr/local/bin/coffee
            node: /usr/local/bin/node
```

I would like to have a custom comment header (see `banner` from example gulpfile) to be appended to my js and css files generated by assetic when I run `assetic:dump` command:

```
$ php app/console assetic:dump
```

I bet this can be done using [custom assetic filters](http://richardmiller.co.uk/2011/05/24/symfony2-make-your-own-assetic-filter/). If someone already did this, would be great, otherwise, I'll be posting here if I get something working.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this using rules on the server app (Apache, Nginx...) the generated assets are just files and they are served directly as the documentation on the .htaccess file says

```
# If the requested filename exists, simply serve it.
# We only want to let Apache serve files and not directories.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule .? - [L]
```